# How to Post an image to Facebook on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6

How to post a status message with one image to Facebook on IOS 6?

Comment: Why is this being voted down?

Comment: @nonamelive My guess is something to do with the lack of effort to ask a specific question, or show what has already been tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add image

```
 [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"]];
```

here is the completed code snippet

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

            NSLog(@"Cancelled");

        } else

        {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }

        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

    [controller setInitialText:@"Test Post from mobile.safilsunny.com"];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com"]];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}
```

If you want to check the step by step procedure to integrate facebook in iOS, then please take a look at my article which is listed in my [blog post](http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/integrating-facebook-ios-6/)